# Recent post thumbnail widget for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am looking for a wordpress plugin that fetches thumbnails from the recent posts in certain category and displays thumbnail along with the post title in the form of widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I don't think you need a plugin for this, is quite simple:

```
<?php 

query_posts('category_name=yourcategory&orderby=date'); 


while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        the_title();
        the_post_thumbnail();

endwhile;


wp_reset_query();

?>
```

Replace 'yourcategory' with your category :)

See more info about the post thumbnail [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail).

Comment: I got what I was looking for using the plugin WP Category Post List Widget